# Returning a value from a from a protractor promise inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I’m trying to get text from a page and then use that text further down in the spec to assert on another element.

I’ve pasted a very simple spec you can run that shows you can’t return a value from a function if the function’s return statement is inside a protractor promise `return txt;` (line 24)…

```
describe('My Test', function () {
    var tempVariable;

    it('should go get some text from the page', function () {
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org/');
        tempVariable = getTextFromElement();    //it appears javascript immediately sets this variable before waiting for protractor to return the value
    });

    it('should do some random other stuff', function () {
        element.all(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Learn')).get(0).click();
        element.all(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Case Studies')).get(0).click();
        element.all(by.cssContainingText('a', ' Home')).get(0).click();
    });

    it('should be able to use the text from the first page in this test', function () {
        console.log('\ntempVariable: ' + tempVariable);    //this is undefined!
        expect(typeof tempVariable).not.toBe('undefined', 'failed: tempVariable was undefined!');
    });
});

function getTextFromElement() {
    $('a.learn-link').getText().then(function (txt) {
        console.log('\nInitial text:   ' + txt);
        return txt;     //how do we return this so it's available to other 'it' blocks?
    });
}
```

Updated snippet of code following @alecxe answer and my comment.

I am attempting to contruct an object from various text on a page and return it to assert on in a later page...

```
function getRandomProductFromList() {
    var Product = function (line, name, subname, units) {
        this.line       = line;
        this.name       = name;
        this.subname    = subname;
        this.units      = units;
    };

    var myProduct = new Product();

    myProduct.line = 'Ford';
    myProduct.units = 235;

    //select a random product on the page and add it to 'myProduct'
    var allProducts = element.all('div.product');
    allProducts.count().then(function (count) {
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
        var productName = allProducts.get(randomIndex);

        productName.getText().then(function (prodName) {
            myProduct.name = prodName;
            productName.click();
        });
    });

    //If a sub-product can be chosen, select it and add it to 'myProduct'
    var subproduct = $('div.subproduct');
    subproduct.isDisplayed().then(function (subProductExists) {
        if (subProductExists) {
            subproduct.getText().then(function (subProductName) {
                myProduct.subname = subProductName;
            });
            subproduct.click();
        }
    }, function (err) {});

    return myProduct;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the code that you want to execute after the return inside an anonymous function and pass it to `getTextFromElements` as a parameter.  Then simply call that parameter as a function where you're trying to return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @alecxe for starting me off on the right foot.

I found a solution I am now using quite a bit after reading [this](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass).

By passing an object by reference, you can add properties on the fly and use them later in your spec.

Example:

```
describe('My Test', function () {
    var tempObject = {};

    it('should go get some text from the page', function () {
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org/');
        getTextFromElement(tempObject);    //pass an object by reference to populate with page text
    });

    it('should do some random other stuff', function () {
        $('div.someDiv').click();
    });

    it('should be able to use the text from the first page in this test', function () {
        console.log(tempObject.textFromFirstPage); //works!
    });
});

function getTextFromElement(tempObject) {
    $('a.some-link').getText().then(function (txt) {
        tempObject.textFromFirstPage = txt;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are *not returning anything from the function*:

```
function getTextFromElement() {
    return $('a.learn-link').getText();
}
```

Now, this function would return you a *promise* which you need to resolve before using:

```
it('should be able to use the text from the first page in this test', function () {
    tempVariable.then(function (tempVariableValue) {
        console.log('\ntempVariable: ' + tempVariableValue);    
        expect(typeof tempVariableValue).not.toBe('undefined', 'failed: tempVariable was undefined!');
    });
});
```

Plus, to determine whether a variable is defined or not, I would use `toBeDefined()` from [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers):

```
expect(tempVariableValue).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: That started me off on the right foot, thanks. It turns out there's a little more to my problem than returning a single promise which I can resolve later down the spec. In my real test, `getTextFromElement()` actually uses `getText()` multiple times to contruct an _object_. And its that _object_ I want to return in order to access it's attributes later in the spec. The different `getText()` functions are scattered throughout the function so I'm not sure where to return the completed object. Do you have any tips for accomplishing something like that instead of returning just one promise?

Comment: @luker02 I think we can solve it. Could you provide the code you have so far and what that object should look like? Thanks!

Comment: Cool. I added a more specific version of my `getTextFromElement()` function to my initial question now called `getRandomProductFromList()`

Comment: @alecxe how do we return value instead of promise from the function?

Comment: @SurendraJnawali we don't, pass promises around and resolve when needed.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. This is working for me:

```
    var item = element.all(by.xpath("some xpath here"));


    this.methodToGetTheText = function () {
       return Promise.resolve(item.getText().then(function (text) {
           return text;
       }));
    }
```

Comment: FYI you can simply call `item.getText()` which does the same thing as your whole `methodToGetTheText` function. But, if you need to modify the text before returning it, simplify to: `this.methodToGetTheText = function () {
    return item.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text.toLowerCase();
    });
}` (you don't need the `Promise.resolve`). If using TypeScript or ES6, simplify even more: `this.methodToGetTheText = () => item.getText().then(text => text.toLowerCase());`

Comment: I cannot simply call item.getText(). If I do that, the method returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `methodToGetTheText().then(` from your spec? The value inside the `.then()` function should contain your actual page text